# Prove that $\frac{d^4\phi}{dx^4}=f(x)$ using integration by parts and fundamental theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

A function f is continuous on $[0,∞)$ and $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{3!}\int_0^x(x−t)^3f(t)dt, x ≥ 0$. Show that
$\frac{d^4\phi}{dx^4}=f(x),\forall x\geq0$.

I can prove this using newton Leibnitz theorem but can't see how to do it by only using fundamental theorem and by parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have, $$\phi(x) =\frac{1}{3!}\left[(x-t)^3\int f(t)dt \bigg|_0^x-3\int_0^x(x-t)^2\left(\int f(u)du\right) dt\right]\\=a_1 -\frac{1}{2!}\int_0^x(x-t)^2 \left(\int f(u)du\right)dt$$ where $a_1$ is some constant. Repeating this process two more times, we’ll get $$\phi(x) = a_1+a_2+a_3+\int_0^x\left(\iiint f(u)\ du\right)dt $$
Notice $a_i$ will always be constants as plugging in $t=x$ makes the term dependent on $x$ vanish. The result follows by FTC from here.

Answer (score 3):

$\phi (x)=\frac 1  6 [x^{3}\int_0^{x} f(t)dt-3x^{2}\int_0^{x} tf(t)dt+3x\int_0^{x} t^{2}f(t)dt-\int_0^{x} t^{3}f(t)dt]$. Now differentiate using product rule and FTC.

Comment: I belive you meant $\phi(x)= \cdots$.

Comment: @Gary Of course. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Can you show one example of differentiating by product rule? For eg. how do we differentiate, $\int_0^xt^2f(t)dt$?

Comment: By FTC the derivative of $\int_0^{x} tf(t)dt $ is $x f(x)$. You don't need product rule for this. @tatan

Answer (score 0):

$$\phi=\frac{1}{3!}\int_0^x(x-t)^3f(t)dt$$
$$\phi'=\frac{(x-x)^3f(x).1}{3!}+\frac 1{2!}\int_0^x(x-t)^2f(t)dt$$
$$\phi''=\frac{(x-x)^2f(x).1}{2!}+\int_0^x(x-t)f(t)dt$$
$$\phi'''=(x-x)f(x).1+\int_0^xf(t)dt$$
$$\phi''''=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(t)dt=f(x)$$
you can do this using the Leibniz integral rule

Comment: how did you do the first derivative? Using which rule?

Comment: @tatan Leibniz integral rule for all parts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule